# Has anyone used Count Items power tool extension with Tridion 2011?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I configured the count items power tool extension by creating a custom page @CME(/Powertools/countitems.asp).
But,it is throwing an error message when i tried to execute the page. I am using Tridion 2011 GA version.Below is the error message which is not very clear in order to troubleshoot the issue.
Please wait while the items are counted.
An error occurred on the server when processing the URL.

do i need to do make any other changes in order to make it work? Please advice.

Comment: If this is still an issue - could you actually paste your error here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you intalled the pre-2011 PowerTool(s). There is a new PowerTool's project available specific for SDL Tridion 2011 and up.

Check out this url: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/

There is an installer available.

Btw, the old PowerTools *should* work. But in order for us to help you, we need the real error you are receiving. Check out the Windows Eventlog on the CMS for a detailed error-message.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative option : You could try using the PowerShell script mentioned here

http://amarchuk.blogspot.com/2012/11/powershell-script-to-gather-some.html